# How does a class differ from a class library?

Tags: .net

I'm a beginner in C#. I searched the web but couldn't find a satisfactory answer to these questions. They may be trivial, but I'm pretty confused.

1. How does a simple class without a `main` differ from a class library ?
2. Can we create a .dll using the C# class template in Visual Studio ?

Comment: Search better and you'll find a lot of useful information ! 1. Class library is a library of classes, interfaces, and value types that are included in the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK ; 2. yes

Comment: A class library is just a dll (usually), of classes. Just away of organising your code, nothing else.

Comment: Then how to use a C# class template to generate a dll on compilation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class library compiles to a `.dll`.  It can contain any number of classes, interfaces, namespaces, modules (vb), and embedded resources.

A class is a single `class`.  It may have nested classes - but those are *usually* considered a **B**ad **T**hing.

You can compile a single ***code*** file using the command line compiler (`csc.exe /target:library` or `vbc.exe /target:library`).

If you are using Visual Studio you must use the *Class Library* template to output a `.dll`.  The *Class* template has nothing to do with project type.